# IPV6 aliases in rc.conf

Tags: freebsd, ipv6, ifconfig, rc

I am currently running FreeBSD `12.0-RELEASE-p2`, and I can't figure out how to create both IPV4 and IPV6 aliases for a loopback (`lo1`) interface using `rc.conf` on boot. Here is a snippet of my `rc.conf`:

```
cloned_interfaces="lo1"
ifconfig_lo1="inet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0"
ifconfig_lo1_ipv6="inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::/48"
ifconfig_lo1_alias0="inet 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255"
ifconfig_lo1_alias1="inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.255"
ifconfig_lo1_alias0_ipv6="inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/64"
ifconfig_lo1_alias1_ipv6="inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::2/64"
```

Unfortunately the last two lines don't seem to function properly (no ipv6 aliases are added). Although I can find references of creating ipv6 aliases within the manpage, there is no indication of how to create them alongside with ipv4 aliases.

I would like to run the equivalent of the following on boot, using `rc.conf`:

```
ifconfig lo1 inet 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 alias
ifconfig lo1 inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 alias
ifconfig lo1 inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/64 alias
ifconfig lo1 inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::2/64 alias
```

EDIT:
I tried modifying my `rc.conf` like so:

```
cloned_interfaces="lo1"
ifconfig_lo1="inet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0"
ifconfig_lo1_ipv6="inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::/48"
ifconfig_lo1_alias0="inet 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255"
ifconfig_lo1_alias1="inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.255"
ifconfig_lo1_alias2="inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::1 prefixlen 64"
ifconfig_lo1_alias3="inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::2 prefixlen 64"
```

And then restarting netif:

```
# service netif restart
Stopping Network: lo0 em0 em1 pflog0 lo1.
-- OTHER INTERFACES EXCLUDED --
lo1: flags=8048<LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx:: prefixlen 48 
    inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::1 prefixlen 64 
    inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx::2 prefixlen 64 
    groups: lo 
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
Destroyed clone interfaces: lo1.
Created clone interfaces: lo1.
Starting Network: lo0 em0 em1 lo1.
-- OTHER INTERFACES EXCLUDED --
lo1: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet6 fdxx:xxxx:xxxx:: prefixlen 48 
    inet 10.0.0.0 netmask 0xffffff00 
    inet 10.0.0.1 netmask 0xffffffff 
    inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 0xffffffff 
    groups: lo 
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

Again, it just seems to ignore the ipv6 addresses, but the following works fine:

```
ifconfig lo1 inet6 fd7e:d071:2503::1/64 alias
ifconfig lo1 inet6 fd7e:d071:2503::2/64 alias
```

Comment: Should not the alias directive come last in the name?

Answer (score 2):

`ifconfig_lo1_alias2`, not `ifconfig_lo1_alias0_ipv6`.  And so on.

This is pointed out specifically in the `rc.conf` manual, with an example.

Comment: I tried this out, although it still doesn't seem to work as expected (see my updated question). Could it be a syntax error in my alias itself?